# Why Ajax post request is executed several times?

Tags: jquery, ajax

here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $("#mainbutton").click(function(){
                $("#ajaxform").submit(function(e){
                    var info = $(this).serialize();
                    $.ajax(
                    {
                        url : "userctrl",
                        type: "post",
                        data : info,
                        success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) 
                        {
                            console.log("success");
                             $('.valid-error').html(data);
                        },
                    });
                    e.preventDefault()
                });
                $("#ajaxform").submit(); //Submit the form
            });
        });
```

and my html

```
        <form id="ajaxform">
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="submit"/>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Name" name="name" id="name" /><span></span>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Surname" name="surname" /><span></span>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Address" name="address" /><span></span>
        <p class="valid-error"></p>
        <input id="mainbutton" class="mainbutton" type="button" value="trial"/>
        </form>
```

this request is executed several times depend on which fields is filled. If I fill two fields will be executed 3 times if I fill 3 fields 4 times. This is not always the case but definitely my doPost method in the servlet is called several times .... I click on the submit button only once !!! Why ?

Comment: On each click you are binding a new submit event

Comment: yes but I am clicking only once

Comment: Im not sure how do you check it but i guess you are doing it wrongly and beware a FORM can be submitted using enter or space in some case and without clicking button, your submit handler wouldnt be called

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because *every time* the button is clicked, you're adding a further `submit` handler to the form. Any time you find yourself hooking up an event handler from *within* another event handler, you want to think carefully if that's really want you want to do (usually, it isn't).

Hook `submmit` *outside* the `click` handler:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#ajaxform").submit(function(e) {
        var info = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
            url: "userctrl",
            type: "post",
            data: info,
            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                console.log("success");
                $('.valid-error').html(data);
            },
        });
        e.preventDefault()
    });
    $("#mainbutton").click(function() {
        $("#ajaxform").submit(); //Submit the form
    });
});
```

Comment: thx this is the explanation. Just to ask u this function $(document).ready(function() - isnt it redundant?

Comment: @oronaparcali: It is if you follow standard web optimization recommendations and put your `script` tags at the **end** of your HTML, just before the closing `</body>` tag, yes. If you don't follow that recommendation, you may need to use `ready` if your `script` is above the elements it acts on in the HTML.

Comment: Thank you. I have one last question. If I want to redirect or forward the request to another page after success ot ajax request - how I can do that? Sorry about lots of questions :)

Comment: @oronaparcali: A couple of different ways: `location.href = "http://example.com";`, `location.replace("http://example.com");`, using the history API...

Comment: Actually I need to forward the request to my servlet. Do u know how?

Comment: @oronaparcali: Servlets are served on URLs just like anything else.

Comment: yes b ut when I use either location.replace("controller") or location.href = "controller"; I get redirect in my browser to http://localhost:8080/Task1/controller but dGet() of my servlet is not called. This is the mapping <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Controller</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/controller</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

Comment: @oronaparcali: Dunno, but this is now very far afield of the question. Good luck,